# How to scale Landscape with Juju

Tags: juju, landscape, scaling

I have an installation of Landscape 23.03 with the Juju Charm [landscape-scalable](https://charmhub.io/landscape-scalable). The installation process has gone fine and according to [the guide](https://ubuntu.com/landscape/docs/juju-installation).

As we have more than 500 servers in our organization we have chosen the "truly scalable" option as described [on this page](https://ubuntu.com/landscape/docs/self-hosted-landscape).

Here's the problem: How do I scale Landscape? I have only been able to find a few lines on [high availability](https://juju.is/docs/olm/high-availability): `juju deploy -n 10 <application>`. Having tried this command with `n=2` was unsuccesfull.

Is the charm not clever enough to setup connections to the postgres database, and edit the HAProxy configs?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charms can be scaled up and down after deployment by using `juju add-unit` or `juju remove-unit` commands. For landscape server, this is a matter of running

```
juju add-unit landscape-server
```

This should allocate a new machine and scale landscape-server to it. As you mentioned, this will also wire the newly deployed landscape-server to haproxy and the database.
Technically the same command could be done for scaling haproxy or postgresql (though in the case of postgres it doesn't quite scale but create a passive replication server IIRC)

`juju deploy` is used to deploy new applications, not scale existing ones. If you were creating a new model from scratch that would be one way to do it. As you already have a functional juju model (deployed with the landscape-scalable bundle) the `deploy` command will probably error saying the application already exists.